# Heroku Node.js build failing: node-gyp throws error during npm install

Tags: node.js, heroku, node-gyp

This morning I got the failure messages below when I tried to push to my Heroku repo.

I am using the same version of Node.js that I did with my last deploy and I cannot find any docs that explain what the failure means.

It seems to be some kind of compile issue with node-gyp but I have no idea how to resolve it.

Here is the console output from the attempted deploy:

```
Enumerating objects: 43, done.
Counting objects: 100% (43/43), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (24/24), done.
Writing objects: 100% (26/26), 16.71 KiB | 2.09 MiB/s, done.
Total 26 (delta 18), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/nodejs
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  14.16.0
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version 14.16.0...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 14.16.0...
remote:        Using default npm version: 6.14.11
remote:
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        - node_modules
remote:
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules
remote:
remote:        > sq-native@1.0.10 install /tmp/build_d06f6627/node_modules/sq-native
remote:        > node ./install.js
remote:
remote:
remote:        > event-loop-stats@1.2.0 install /tmp/build_d06f6627/node_modules/event-loop-stats
remote:        > node-gyp rebuild
remote:
remote:        make: Entering directory '/tmp/build_d06f6627/node_modules/event-loop-stats/build'
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/eventLoopStats/src/eventLoopStats.o
remote:        In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:56,
remote:                         from ../src/eventLoopStats.cc:1:
remote:        /app/.cache/node-gyp/14.16.0/include/node/node.h:758:43: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘void (*)(Nan::ADDON_REGISTER_FUNCTION_ARGS_TYPE)’ {aka ‘void (*)(v8::Local<v8::Object>)’} to ‘node::addon_register_func’ {aka ‘void (*)(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, void*)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
remote:          758 |       (node::addon_register_func) (regfunc),                          \
remote:              |                                           ^
remote:        /app/.cache/node-gyp/14.16.0/include/node/node.h:792:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘NODE_MODULE_X’
remote:          792 |   NODE_MODULE_X(modname, regfunc, NULL, 0)  // NOLINT (readability/null_usage)
remote:              |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
remote:        ../src/eventLoopStats.cc:95:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘NODE_MODULE’
remote:           95 | NODE_MODULE(eventLoopStats, init)
remote:              | ^~~~~~~~~~~
remote:          SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/eventLoopStats.node
remote:          COPY Release/eventLoopStats.node
remote:        make: Leaving directory '/tmp/build_d06f6627/node_modules/event-loop-stats/build'
remote:
remote:        > ejs@2.7.4 postinstall /tmp/build_d06f6627/node_modules/ejs-mate/node_modules/ejs
remote:        > node ./postinstall.js
remote:
remote:
remote:        > bcrypt@5.0.1 install /tmp/build_d06f6627/node_modules/bcrypt
remote:        > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
remote:
remote:        [bcrypt] Success: "/tmp/build_d06f6627/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node" is installed via remot
remote:
remote:        > @sp/omega@0.9.4 postinstall /tmp/build_d06f6627/node_modules/@sp/omega
remote:        > npm run build-files
remote:
remote:
remote:        > @sp/omega@0.9.4 build-files /tmp/build_d06f6627/node_modules/@sp/omega
remote:        > omega build
remote:
remote:        sh: 1: omega: Permission denied
remote:        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote:        npm ERR! errno 126
remote:        npm ERR! @sp/omega@0.9.4 build-files: `omega build`
remote:        npm ERR! Exit status 126
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Failed at the @sp/omega@0.9.4 build-files script.
remote:        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.4dZx9/_logs/2021-04-06T16_09_47_101Z-debug.log
remote:        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote:        npm ERR! errno 126
remote:        npm ERR! @sp/omega@0.9.4 postinstall: `npm run build-files`
remote:        npm ERR! Exit status 126
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Failed at the @sp/omega@0.9.4 postinstall script.
remote:        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.4dZx9/_logs/2021-04-06T16_09_47_164Z-debug.log
remote:
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to beta-???????????-net.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/beta-???????????-net.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/beta-???????????-net.git'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error happens when Heroku tries to `npm install event-loop-stats`. We know that because of this line in the error message.

```
make: Entering directory '/tmp/build_d06f6627/node_modules/event-loop-stats/build'
```

That module uses `gyp` because installing it requires compiling some C++ - language stuff to make it work. On i[ts npm page at the bottom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/event-loop-stats#node-version-compatibility) there's a notice about compatibility. Following the [link on that notice](https://travis-ci.org/github/bripkens/event-loop-stats) shows that it works on node v6, v10, and v12. But you tell Heroku to use v14.

[Tell heroku to use v12](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version)  by putting this in your package.json

```json
 "engines": {
    "node": "12.x"
```

Comment: This worked when I deployed to Heroku yesterday with node 14.16.0. But it is failing today. The only change to my `package.json` is the addition of the following: `@babel/eslint-parser`, `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties`, `@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods`, `@babel/preset-env`

Comment: OK. It's possible one of those packages you added pulled in `event-loop-stats`. You might be able to figure out which one by looking at package-lock.json.  My suggestion for working around your problem stands.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I just can't switch back to node 12. I use many of the features of 14.8+

Comment: it looks like `event-loop-stats` is loaded by `express-status-monitor@1.3.3` which I was also using yesterday. This make no sense...

Comment: I found where `event-loop-stats` was coming from and worked around that. Thank you for the pointers.